# How to find user ids whose local time is not between start time and end time given their timezone?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timezone

```
create table test(user_id integer not null primary key, tz varchar(64) not null, dnd_start_time integer, dnd_end_time integer);
```

- I have a table test created as follows which stores a user_id, the user's timezone in string format and the do not disturb start time and end time
- How do I select all users whose local time is NOT between start time and end time as per their timezone?
- The table looks as follows

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT user_id
FROM (SELECT user_id,
             make_time(dnd_start_time, 0, 0) AS stime,
             make_time(dnd_end_time, 0, 0) AS etime,
             CAST((current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE tz) AS time) AS loctime
      FROM test)
WHERE stime <= etime AND loctime NOT BETWEEN stime AND etime
   OR stime > etime AND loctime BETWEEN etime AND stime;
```

Comment: thank you sooo much! i had no idea this query was so complicated, does storing tz like a string take DST into account, also there should be an alias after from test :)

Comment: Yes, time zones in this shape will respect daylight savings time.